# More lights = darker object? (see Pictures)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, lighting

So, I rendered a scene and I was very happy with the lighting, but I wanted more to the image, so I moved things around and added a background object. Now the lighting is totally messed up. No matter what I do the Logo Shape won't light up the same way. The face just won't light up. Here are some pictures:
[image: Nicely lit Logo]

And here is the most recent render: [image: Render with Dark Logo]

Here is the blender file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bLsiB4DCggrthn-skXoKDreGBCGBQ4a9/view?usp=sharing

It's missing some textures, but it should be the same otherwise.

Comment: Suggest you add a screenshot of your Shader editor for that material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logo in the second image has some Subsurface shading.

I would suggest for the moment to go back to basics,

1: Clean up your logo shader so that it isn't using any subsurf.

[image]

2: Replace all your lights with a couple of area lamps.

[image]

result is :

[image]

Now you can go back and set up shaders and lights as required.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked! Now the only question I have is why? Any Idea?

Comment: With SubSurface Scattering the light penetrates the surface and is scattered about inside. The thicker the object the more the light will be absorbed but on thinner parts the light will exit again. You can see this effect on the logo in your second image. It looks almost as if the logo is lit from within.